# What are the features of microcontrollers used in space?

Tags: technology, flight-computer

What are the most desired features of microcontrollers used in space in on-board computers? Are there some special implementations, special functionality? Are features of some microcontrollers not accepted at all in space and thus some architectures are not taken into account?

Comment: If you click on the flight-computer tag and read around, you'll find examples of ordinary computers being used successfully. Whether something is "accepted" depends on the customer really.

Comment: A broad range of systems is in use, depending on type of mission. Longterm deepspace missions have different requirements than low earth orbit manned missions. Please indicate what you are after. As a general thought, radiation hardness is prerequisite to most missions.

Comment: I believe you could compare with a car, they have loads of computers inside them today. One of them controls the engine in real time, reading temperatures and airflow and so on, and controlling sparks and fuel flows and lots of other things. One extremely important aspect there is reliability -- your brand new BMW should not stop on the road due to a 5 cent resistor failing. In order to reach reliability you start by a well-known design and do a lot of environmental testing. Same as in space. So the designs tend to lean towards well-known conservative.